# Flow Router not working with google maps?

Tags: google-maps, meteor

For some strange reason whenever I try to route google maps into a flow router layout it never renders. The google maps template i'm using looks like this:

```
<template name="map">
    {{> googleMap name="map" options=mapOptions}}
</template>
```

Is this a glitch with flowrouter?

Comment: What are you using for the `googleMap` template? How are your route and layout defined? Any errors in the console?

Comment: @MasterAM I'm using the dburles:google-maps package, no errors in the console and router is set properly, just doesn't work with google maps. FlowRouter.route('/', {
    name: 'main',
    action() {
        BlazeLayout.render('MainLayout', { 
        nav: "navigation", body: "map"
        });
    }
});

Comment: probably better to edit the question to add the data with proper formatting :)